# How come I can't migrate in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Migration files in laravel is used to create the tables in the database, right? But when ever I try to migrate it gives me this error:

> C:\xampp\htdocs\app>php artisan migrate
>
> [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
>     SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'users' already exists (SQL: create table `users` (
>     `id` int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `name` varchar(255) not null, `email` varchar(255) not null,
>     `password` varchar(255) not null, `remember_token` varchar(100) null, `created_at` timestamp null, `updated_at` tim
>     estamp null) default character set utf8mb4 collate utf8mb4_unicode_ci)
>
> [PDOException]
>     SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'users' already exists

---

and I created a new migration file and it's called test. I know users already exist but I want create the new table I created which is called test.

here is the migration file i am going to use to create my table but wont create:

```
    <?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateTestsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('tests', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('tests');
    }
}
```

here is the users migration file that tells me it exist:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
}
```

here is the password migration file:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreatePasswordResetsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('password_resets', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('email')->index();
            $table->string('token');
            $table->timestamp('created_at')->nullable();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('password_resets');
    }
}
```

here is the dummies migration file i have that i didn't talk about because i thought it is not the problem:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateDummiesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('dummies', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->text('body');
            $table->timestamp('date'); //if you dont put name for the timestamp it will create: create_at and update_at fields.
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('dummies');
    }
}
```

and sorry for keeping you guys waiting it took me long to find the edit button and fix the spacing of my code. It is my first time using stack over flow.

Answer (score 2):

The `migrations` table in your database is out of sync with the rest of your database. Laravel is trying to re-run a migration to create the `users` table and failing.

If this is an entirely new project, you could delete all tables from your database and re-run all migrations. Alternatively, fix your migration table so that it accurately reflects the state of your database.

Comment: I dropped all my tables in the database and it still wont create my new tables. It only created my users table and migrations table. It didn't create my test table.

Comment: @Lami what error did you receive this time? And can you please post the code for all of your migrations (including filenames).

Comment: @Vandolph Reyes I edited my post and added the test migration file.

Comment: @Lami - you must have more than one migration file, because Laravel is complaining about a `users` table. Please include all migrations and their filenames. Filenames are important, because they denote the order in which the migrations are executed.

Answer (score 0):

In your laravel/app/providers/AppServiceProvider.php
add the following code inside boot

```
Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
```

Then try `php artisan migrate:refresh`

or best

drop all tables and run `php artisan migrate` again

Answer (score 0):

Add following code in the start of your up function() of all tables

```
public function up()
{
        // Add this line
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
        // from you down method
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            ...........
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
*// AppServiceProvider.php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

function boot()
{
    Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
}
*
```